# Need precision on iOS notch

Tags: codenameone

I really have issues understanding how to handle the top notch on iPhone.  I use a css in which I added the following snippet

```
#Constants {
    includeNativeBool: true;
...
Default {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

Form {
    cn1-derive: Default;
}

Toolbar {
    cn1-derive: Form;
}

StatusBar { /* This is required on the very top on iOS */
    cn1-derive: Toolbar;
    padding: 13px;/*mandatory*/
}
```

but still it shows wrong on iPhone with the top notch.  OK, the statusbar padding is set to 13px but how to make this value depend on the phone it's running? Can you help tell me what I am missing?
[image]

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

This is set to the right amount of padding by default so I would recommend you just remove the definition of status bar entirely. It's transparent and padded with millimeters when applicable e.g. in Android it's 0px but on iOS it has 2 millimeters. This isn't a lot for iOS and things can appear tight (which is what some developers want) so you might want to have another millimeter or two of padding in the Toolbar if you override padding.

Comment: Yes.  It makes sense.  It's so obvious now you said it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Quick question though: how does this behave when in landscape?

Comment: You would still get spacing in landscape since the clock/battery indicator etc will still be there.

Comment: Yes, OK.  Do you get rid of the space allowed for the notch on some iPhones when in landscape?

Comment: Sorry, Shai.  I got misled by the simulator that does not show the "clock/battery indicator etc" in landscape mode for th eiphoneX skin.  Please ignore my previous comment.